# CSS Minimize and compress on fly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to ask how this works.

when I load this file I see from chrome dev tool / Network tab 151kb
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/material-fullpalette.min.css

actually with other tool  the actual size is 2,111,460 bytes  ~2MB

if I want to host by myself this file what are the steps to replicate same result as cloudflare?

I can not afford 2MB per unique user I would like to keep it 151kb

question 2
What is the role of last:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=material-fullpalette.min.css.map */
```

Comment: there are [many easy-to-find CSS minifiers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+minify&oq=css+mini&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.1975j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) online for free. you wouldn't minimize on-the-fly; since your CSS is static you just minimize once and then upload the minimized version to your server.

Comment: if the stylesheet you linked is all you want, you don't even have to minimize it yourself. just download the already-minified version from the CDN and upload it to your server.

Comment: actually I did that with minimum 4 tools this is not the case. There is minimaze + hosting gzip + something else I need the something else to know

Comment: the file is 151kb ,  it's imposibble for it is to be 2MB if there's not additional content

Comment: if you install Quick source viewer tool for chrome you can see the full 2MB  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-source-viewer/cfmcghennfbpmhemnnfjhkdmnbidpanb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon   what about my second question?

Comment: *"actually with other tool"* - what tool? Can you share a reference to this 2mb file?

Comment: well the other tool is the link above 'quick-source-viewer' I like it. My problem was I didn't notice that I am loading the full version NOT Minimized when I paste it in CSS Editor I got my answer. Obviously related to my second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **If I want to host by myself this file what are the steps to replicate same result as cloudflare?**

You can't unless you have top-notch servers in different parts of the world ready to deliver content to users via a server nearest to them (that is how CloudFlare and other CDN providers provide content faster than your server btw).

---

> **What is the role of last: /*# sourceMappingURL=material-fullpalette.min.css.map */**

Those `.map` files called `source maps`, and are used by browser debuggers to display compiled CSS (LESS,SASS, etc) in a readable format.

Comment: Yes I would like to host by myself on Azure or Amazon or Akamai CDNs  but the file is 2MB the full size then it is minified 200bytes... what you are saying that the ~2MB what I see is comming from the MAP?

Comment: Not really sure what you are talking about.